# Cannot run docker 'hello world' example

Tags: docker

I just installed docker on a Mac (`docker toolbox` from [here](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox); at least I hope to have it installed correctly), but when following the [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/#setup) and type the following command

```
docker run hello-world
```

I get the following error:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

Did I do something wrong? Do I miss some installation steps? Do I miss something that is 'obvious' to the experts, but not to `docker` beginners like me?

I don't see anything in the instructions that says anything about a 'docker daemon'...

On the shell it says:

```
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP aa.bb.cc.d
```

The version command seems to work:

```
Docker version 17.07.0-ce, build 8784753
```

Update:

I tried to start the daemon by using the command

```
sudo dockerd
```

but all I got was

```
sudo: dockerd: command not found
```

Correction: The command works, but only in the sell that opened magically during the installation. The command does not work in any other shell. But when I have to close the shell/restart the computer - what to do then? How to 'start docker???

Maybe there is a tutorial that is complete and working and explains why I need a docker-deacon, how to start it, how to start a docker image or whatever, including the complete terminology for beginners?

Comment: You can start from Spotlight search or ./Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker & would work. Docker daemon required to build/run any images. You will see a whale kinda symbol on your task bar, if docker is running.

Comment: I want to use command line commands only. Well, docker is running, but I can do something only from one terminal. It does not work from another terminal...

Comment: How to check if the daemon is running? How to start a daemon? I sure with `docker run` I start a docker image? I am not even sure how to ask the question

Comment: Ok, currently there is no command for bringing up docker daemon, instead, you can use this command `nohup ./Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker & ` so that it won't be specific to terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker Toolbox runs a virtual linux machine on which the docker-daemon runs. To control the virtual machine, you use the `docker-machine` command. For example `docker-machine start` to start the machine after you reboot your computer, or `docker-machine stop` to shut it down.

There is also the `docker-machine env` command which will set the environment variables needed for `docker` to work. Check the bottom line of it's output, it shows you how to run the command correctly to set the environment variables. Should be `exec $(docker-machine env)` on Mac if I'm correct. You need to set the environment variables in each shell in which you want to use `docker` commands.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks a lot for the explanation. I wonder why these essential informations are always missing from a tutorial. Oh, maybe because its a stupid Mac...

Comment: They expect you to run the "docker toolbox shell" each time you want to use docker, in which everything is set up for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

With docker toolbox, if you don't launch your terminal from the docker menu, you'll need to configure your environment separately:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker for mac starts a linux virtual machine in the background which contains the actual docker stuff. When you start a normal terminal, the terminal is not connected to the vm to execute the docker commands.

The docker quick start terminal is the one that you need to use. This terminal will execute the commands on the VM that is running in the background.

Comment: Ah that is good to know. But how to start this virtual machine again? Say, I restart the computer. How to recreate that virtual machine again?

Comment: @Alex It will start automatically.

Comment: I seriously doubt that. Its a 'Mac'!!